# After Android SDK upgrade: why does RecyclerView not show items correctly?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-recyclerview

I recently upgraded the `build.gradle` settings in Android Studio for a working app.  The UI output for the items in the `RecyclerView` list is not showing properly anymore.  What am I missing here?

```
compileSdkVersion from 23 to 24
buildToolsVersion 23.0.2 to 24.0.1
targetSdkVersion from 23 to 24
```

The three file dependencies were updated from 23.1.1 to 24.1.1,

from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
```

Prior to upgrade, three RecyclerView items showed properly:

[image]

After upgrade, there is a very large amount of new whitespace between the items and the UI only shows one full item and the bottom of one of the other items.

[image]

Comment: If you check release notes of v23.2.0, you will be able to see that now, RecyclerView does not ignore some LayoutParams anymore... Maybe, that's why the error is happening. Post your layouts.. this way, we will be able to help:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#

Comment: Based on that, try to call setAutoMeasureEnabled(true) in the layout manager before set it to RecyclerView

Comment: Ah, ok.  I will try to change item layout height from match_parent to wrap_content.

Comment: That did the trick.  Cheers!

Comment: What fixed? set setAutoMeasureEnabled(true)? If yes, I'll place as answer for future references...

Comment: I had to change the height parameter in the item layout file.  Previously the height parameter (match_parent in this case) was ignored as a layout parameter but is now fully respected.  So changing from match_parent to wrap_content did the trick.